# what process do you go through when deciding whether move up or down in a progression? (ue move up a 4th or move down a 5th?)

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

The question sounds pretty dumb I'd imagine & I'll have a hard time trying to convey my thoughts, but I'll try...

Those of you that are experienced in writing, what kind of thoughts go through your head when you decide to move UP or move DOWN to connect different chords in a progression?

For example, in C Major, lots of songs start out by playing (I-V).

How do you decide whether to play C-E-G, then move up in pitch (to the right on piano) & play G-B-D

OR

play C-E-G, then move down in pitch (to the left on piano) & play G-B-D, down there?

What type of emotion or feel would be conveyed either way?

Take the Beatles - Let It Be, using 1-5-6-4. The G chord is played DOWN a 4th, correct?

Even though on the Circle Of 5ths chart, the G is placed as "UP a 5th".

Comment: This question is probably too opinion-based for the site. A few of many factors: if you are playing in a lower register and want some variety, you might move up, or vice-versa; voice-leading is always a factor; the chord movement might follow the melody up or down; you might be developing a bass-line that guides which way to move; you might play inversions and not move much in either direction....

Comment: Everyone has their own process. Questions about “what process do you use?” are essentially opinion/survey questions.

Comment: You do neither. You usually play chord inversions. You decide which inversion based on voice leading (look it up), where you are in the instruments register and what the melody note does.

Comment: This question can be considered opinion based but it also shows the OP may be unaware of using inversions for smoother chord transitions which I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are going on the assumption that chords have to be played from the root up. This is not the case at all. When moving from one chord to another the most common and most logical thing to do is to use inversions of chords — so as not to have large jumps from one to the other. In case you’re not familiar, an inversion of a chord is when the notes are the same but played in a different order from bottom to top. Take your C chord, CEG. it can also be played with the E on the bottom, EGC (called first inversion) and with the G on the bottom, GCE (called second inversion).

Using your I-V example of Let it Be in C, the first chord can be CEG but rather than playing a G a 5th higher or a 4th lower it makes more sense to play a G in second inversion. Then you go from CEG to BDG. The top note G is a common tone and should be in the same register on both chords. Everything stays in close proximity and the notes flow smoothly from one chord to the other.

There are other options, you can play the C in 2nd inversion, GCE then the G in root position GBD. The third option is the C in 1st inversion EGC to the G in 2nd inversion DGB. In each case the G is a common note, the E moves a step down to D and the C moves a half step down to B.

Here is one bar from a transcription on YouTube. As you can see the right hand goes from a C root position to a G in 1st inversion:

[image]

This is referred to as good voice leading, where the notes from one chord flow smoothly into the next. It is an acquired skill pianists and guitarists develop over time.

There can be purposeful motion up and down when changing chords like you say. The emotional effect would be subjective so no objective judgements can be made about that.

Answer (score 1):

As a practical matter I think it has to do with range. If you need to stay within a certain range (singer's range, fingering requirements, timbral reason like muddy bass region, or contrapuntal reasons like trying to keep voices from crossing) you might choose accordingly.

> What type of emotion or feel would be conveyed either way?

There are some emotional/expressive associations with direction and range. Up and high can be a brighter mood or energizing, etc. Down and low can be dark or reposing. But that kind of thing is *very* subjective, and you can easily flip those notions. Just bang hard on the bass range of the piano and you get booming sounds instead of repose. A lot depends on how abstract the music is to begin with.

There is very little difference between these two...

[image]

...although if you did this...

[image]

...the up to down of `G3` to `G2` sets up a kind of antecedent/consequent, question/answer type of dynamic. I would not call that an "emotional" choice, it's about phrasing, and it's pretty subtle.

If you want upper/lower to have some expressive impact, I think you still need to use rhythmic and expressive elements, maybe something like this...

[image]

...the first has the bright uplift in the high range with a quick octave figuration,  the second emphasizes the repose of the low range with slow rhythm and soft dynamics. The point is particular octave has less to do with the expressive impact than the other elements. Just to make that point emphatically, reverse the octaves...

[image]

...the effect hardly changes.

> Take the Beatles - Let It Be, using 1-5-6-4. The G chord is played DOWN a 4th, correct?

That song will so loaded with meaning and associations for people that it becomes difficult to use as an general example. *Someone* will find deep philosophical meaning in the chord voicings simply because they want to. But, it's just as likely the choices were made because it fit the hand.